# The reason for a 'free' box in an ISO BMFF or MP4 file?

Tags: mp4, codec, mpeg, mpeg-4

It's easy to spot a **free** box in a .mp4 (or ISO BMFF) file. I'm wondering the reason for this box. Is it some sort of padding for file size? Sometimes, I even spotted two consecutive **free** boxes!

The following is a partial info by **mp4dump**

```
[ftyp] size=8+20
  major_brand = iso5
  minor_version = 0
  compatible_brand = avc1
  compatible_brand = iso5
  compatible_brand = dash
[free] size=8+17
[moov] size=8+637
  [mvhd] size=12+108, version=1
    timescale = 24000
    duration = 14315000
    duration(ms) = 596458
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually [padding](http://www.cnwrecovery.com/manual/MP4FileLayouts.html) boxes, so that other sections can be correctly aligned (it is also ease [updates](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/mpeg-4files.html)).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like those padding boxes (**free**) are designed for recording/capturing devices than playback?

Comment: I don't think so although they are generated at file creation, while boxes are added, to guarantee (I guess) a fast navigation through the structures.

Comment: It has nothing to do with navigation. It's about the ability to change variables sized boxes without having to recalculate a bunch of offsets within other boxes

Comment: Thanks for that correction, please feel free to add an answer if mine is not accurate